# How to Optimize Google Big Query Bytes Billed

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have recently discovered Google Big Query and it's open datasets. Upon performing the following query on the `311_service requests` table in the `new_york` dataset, the cloud console reports the `bytes billed` to be `130 MB`.

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT unique_key FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york.311_service_requests` LIMIT 10
```

**Query Returns:**

```
+------+-------------+
| Rows | unique_key  |
+------+-------------+
| 1    | 37911459    |
| 2    | 38162601    |
| 3    | 32560181    |
| 4    | 38259076    |
| 5    | 36034528    |
| 6    | 36975822    |
| 7    | 38028455    |
| 8    | 37993135    |
| 9    | 37988664    |
| 10   | 35382611    |
+------+-------------+
```

For a query returning such a small amount of data, why is the bytes billed valued at 130 MB?

Is there a way to optimize this? Should the results of a query be stored in another database for later retrieval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is the bytes billed valued at 130 MB?

Query pricing refers to the cost of running your SQL commands and user-defined functions. BigQuery charges for queries by using one metric: the number of bytes processed (also referred to as bytes read). You are charged for the number of bytes processed whether the data is stored in BigQuery or in an external data source such as Cloud Storage, Google Drive, or Cloud Bigtable.

When you run a query, you're charged according to the total data processed in the columns you select, even if you set an explicit LIMIT on the results. The total bytes per column is calculated based on the types of data in the column. For more information about how we calculate your data size, see Data size calculation.

Query pricing is based on your usage pattern: a monthly flat rate for queries or pricing based on interactive queries. Enterprise customers generally prefer flat-rate pricing for queries because that model offers consistent month-to-month costs. On-demand (or interactive) pricing offers flexibility and is based solely on usage.

You can see more at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

So, in your case 130MB is the size of the respective `unique_key` column

> Should the results of a query be stored in another database for later retrieval?

sure
You can do so to manage cost for consecutive processing of that small data w/o touching the original one
Have in mind - this will invoke storage price for you - see same above mentioned link for details

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. Are there any other querying techniques that would result in lower costs?

Comment: Sure - you can check [BigQuery Best Practices: Controlling Costs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs) and in specific use case you will get into  - just post new question and we will help you